# Custom Rest API for custom table not wroking

Tags: module, custom, rest-api, magento2.3.1

My webapi.xml is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
     <route url="/V1/garage/insert/" method="POST">
        <service class="Garage\Motogaadi\Api\GarageInsert" method="insert"/>
        <resources>
           <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Also my di.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Garage\Motogaadi\Api\GarageInsert" type="Garage\Motogaadi\Model\GarageAdd" />
</config>
```

My interface is below.

```
<?php
namespace Garage\Motogaadi\Api;

interface GarageInsert
{

    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $data Users name.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */

    public function  insert($data);
}
```

My model is below

```
<?php
namespace Garage\Motogaadi\Model;
use Garage\Motogaadi\Api\GarageInsert;

class GarageAdd implements GarageInsert
{

    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $data Users name.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */

    public function insert($data)
    {   


        //Customize the code as per your requirement.
        $cid = $data['id'];
        $gid = $data['gid'];
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('garage_customer_ids');
        $sql = "Insert Into " . $tableName . " ( customer_id, garage_data_id) Values ('$cid','$gid')";     
        $connection->query($sql);       
        return 'successfully saved';

    }
}
```

I get the below error when I post the data.

"message": "The \"array\" value's type is invalid. The \"string\" type was expected. Verify and try again.",

Comment: Check my updated answer. This both option working for array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change parameter type in your interface. Set `$data` type "**array**" from "**string**" :

```
<?php
namespace Garage\Motogaadi\Api;

interface GarageInsert
{

    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param array $data
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */

    public function  insert($data);
}
```

You can add this one also : `* @param string[] $data`

Comment: Thanks. But I get this "message": "Class array does not exist", error. I tried both string[] and array

Comment: You need to change in model file also. Happy coding !! :)

Comment: Annotation is the definition of calling function. so you must give the related type parameter. you are absolutely right @RohanHapani

Answer (score 2):

Please remove **generated** directory and run below command once to fix **type error occurred when creating object** error

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thansk for your comment. I have edited my issue in this question would you pls check

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: Can you please check what value you're getting in this variables ?

$cid = $data['id'];
$gid = $data['gid'];

Comment: Otherwise please set $cid =1;$gid =2; and check it will work

Comment: I have tried both but still I receive same error

Comment: What value you're getting in that both variables ?

Comment: I tried echo the $cid and $gid also tried print_r the $data but the same error which i posted in question repeats

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102019/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-ramesh-kr).